# How to Authenticate Minecraft Login/Any other website login

Tags: java, authentication

So I know that this may have come up a few times, but this is actually a little different. I want to authenticate a login from the authentication server. This is my code:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class TestConnect {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    String host = "https://authserver.mojang.com";
    String user = "--username--";
    String pass = "--password--";

    try {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, user, pass);
    } catch (SQLException err) {
        System.out.println(err.getMessage());
    }
}
```

So the error im getting everytime is the following:

```
No driver found for https://authserver.mojang.com
```

A little help would be welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Read the getConnection method's doc:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Properties)

url - a database url of the form jdbc:subprotocol:subname

Your url is not valid.